# Understand about maximum a posteriori probability (MAP) in classfication task

Tags: bayes-theorem, image-processing, pattern-recognition

I have a 2D image defined on a region $\Omega$. Let $I: \Omega \to R$ be a gray image. Assume that the region can be separated into $N$ sub-regions $\Omega_i$ such that $$\forall i,j=1... N:\Omega_i \cap\Omega_j=\emptyset$$ and $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}\Omega_n =\Omega$$

To simplify, we assume $N=3$ and it shows in below figure.

[image]

We denotes $p(x \in \Omega_i|I(x))$ is posteriori probability of region $\Omega_i$ given $I(x)$. Based on the Bayesian rules, we have

$$p(x \in \Omega_i|I(x))=\frac{p(I(x)|x\in \Omega_i)p(x\in \Omega_i)}{p(I(x))}$$

The segmentation try to assign pixel $x$ to each region based on posteriori probability. That goal is that finds maximum a posteriori probability (MAP) of pixel $x$ in each region. It can express by formula

$$\{ \Omega_{i,x} \}_{i=1}^{N}=\arg \max_{\Omega_i} \{\prod_{i=1}^{N} p(I(x)|x \in \Omega_i)p(x \in \Omega_i )\} \tag{*}$$

Assuming that the pixels within each region are independent , the MAP will be achieved over all image domain $\Omega$
$$\{ \Omega_i \}_{i=1}^{N}=\arg \max_{\Omega_i} \{\prod_{i=1}^{N}\prod_{x \in \Omega_i} p(I(x)|x \in \Omega_i)p(x \in \Omega_i )\} \tag{**}$$

Are my formulas (*) and (**) correct? If not, Could you help me to correct them? Thanks

The reference link is http://vision.mas.ecp.fr/pub/ijcv02-01.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your formula must be as following:
$$\Omega=\arg \max_{\Omega_i} \{ p(x \in \Omega_i|I(x))\} \tag{*}$$

since you want to find the state of the pixel $x$ (namely $\Omega_1$, $\Omega_2$, or $\Omega_3$), not $x$ itself.

Comment: Thank you so much. I corrected them. Could you look at again my update question and verify help me (*) and (**) are correct or not?

Comment: No. Usually it is supposed that only one $\Omega_i$ maximize the right hand side of $(*)$ and $(**)$, so the left hand side must be $\hat\Omega(x) $ I think.

Comment: Thank for your comment. It is very useful for me. Actually, I based on the explanation of Eq 3 in that paper https://www.dropbox.com/s/59c60qagipl8ei0/107001_1.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Thank user153245 for your comment. I accepted it. Anw, I make a final explanation of above problem. Could you look at the more detail in below link and let me know any mistake (if it has)? I highlight the range of argmax by yellow color. Is it correct? https://www.dropbox.com/s/9pxxh25wfk2qol3/MAP.JPG?dl=0